# ¿Porqué recibo el error "ReferenceError: setTimeOut is not defined?

Tags: javascript, css, funciones, bucle-for, timeout

Estoy incursionando en usar setTimeOut y me topé con el error que incorporé al título. Mi intención es simplemente aplicar display:none; a los elementos luego de un 1000ms cuando son clickeados.
¿Alguien sabe el porqué del error y, en un sentido más amplio, si estoy bien encaminado para lograr mi cometido?

Dejo el proyecto para que puedan verlo con más claridad.
https://codepen.io/franguerre/pen/gOWmGKr?editors=1010

Muchas gracias!

```javascript
function darFuncionalidadItems() {
  let childrenArr = Array.from(contenedor.children);
  let timeOut = 0;

  for(let i = 0; i < childrenArr.length; i++) {
    childrenArr[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      /* agrega class con efecto de transición */
      childrenArr[i].classList.add("esconder");
      /* timer para aplicar display:none; una vez que el efecto de transición termine */
      timer(childrenArr[i]);
    }
    );
  }
}

/* timer para quitar elemento una vez terminado el efecto de transición */
function timer(e) {
    setTimeOut(() => {
    e.style.display = "none";
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Error de tecleo, la función correcta es [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), con `o` en minúscula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparte del error mencionado en comentarios, no es necesario usar un temporizador; con solo CSS puedes aplicar una animación y hacer que se conserven las propiedades de la última regla de animación agregando `forwards`.

No es posible animar la propiedad `display`, pero puedes escalar hasta cero, solo configura los pasos en `@keyframes` de acuerdo a tu gusto y necesidades.

En caso de que aún requieras hacer algo cuando termine la animación, puedes escuchar el evento [animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) que resultará más efectivo que un temporizador.

```js
// Asignar evento click al documento
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // Aplicar solo si el clic se realizó en un elemento con clase box
    if(e.target.classList.contains('box')) {
        // Asignar clase para esconder
        e.target.classList.add('esconder');
        // Saber cuando termina la animación
        e.target.addEventListener('animationend', e => {
            console.log('Terminó la animación para:', e.target);
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}
.red { background: red; }
.blue { background: blue; }
.yellow { background: yellow; }

.esconder {
    /* Ajusta el tiempo (1s) y tipo de animación (linear, ease, etc.) */
    animation: esconder 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes esconder {
    0% { transform: scale(1); }
    70% { transform: scale(0.2); }
    /* Conservar un momento antes de ocultar */
    97% { transform: scale(0.2); }
    /* Ocultar sin recurrir a display */
    100% { transform: scale(0); }
}
```

```html
<div class="box red"></div>
<div class="box blue"></div>
<div class="box yellow"></div>
```